# How to verify whether the document name exist in document library?

Tags: list, document-library, file-upload, duplicate

I am uploading some document in sharepoint document library with name sample.txt and after some time I am uploading a document with the same name.

As per the OOB functionality based on the checkbox selection in a popup, either it will add as a new version to existing files or add new file.

Is that possible to show a message in the upload form like "Document name already exist in library" so I can avoid losing some orginal data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a event reciever "ItemAdding - An item is being added"
In that event reciever you can check whether a file with the name exists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728093.aspx

Thanks
Dhanya